# Confused about spinOnce and sleep

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to go a little deeper into the "why" from a *technical perspective*. Not just *you must do this*, but why. I've looked at the rospy source code but I am still not sure about the following. Given this very common pattern:

```
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
       # do stuff
        rate.sleep()
```

Why is a rospy.spinOnce() not required? Or is it required? Because when I read the source of rate.sleep() didn't see that sleep include the spinOnce functionality which would imply that callbacks wouldn't be happening as a result of .sleep() or of is_shutdown(). But in fact callbacks do seem to be happening, so I must be misunderstanding a detail.

#### Refined restatement

Let me restate this in a very focused way. In python when must spin() used and when is spinOnce() used?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375111/confused-about-spinonce-and-sleep/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2021-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-31**:\

> The initial two commenters contradict each other which shows that this is a tricky thing to really understand!

not really.

The answer is incorrect. @Delb's comment is correct.

This has also been discussed before here on ROS Answers.

`roscpp` and `rospy` just have different threading models.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-03-31**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for your comment.

I would like to revise my answer. Could you please let me know the deficiencies?

I would like to describe my perception. I was answering about "Why is a rospy.spinOnce() not required? Or is it required?"
I understand that @Delb has supplemented about spin() in python.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-31**:
The question is specifically about `rospy`.

You link to `roscpp` tutorials and state the same "should apply to Python". But that's not correct.

`roscpp` and `rospy` handle these things differently.

@Delb already made that clear.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-03-31**:
Thank you. I'm going to leave the answers and comments as they are now.
I thought about deleting the wrong comment, but I think it would make @Delb's comment a bit confusing.
If there is a good way to fix it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To clearly answer your question and remove any doubt :

> Why is a rospy.spinOnce() not required ?

- Because it doesn't exist, I'm not sure why you would ask that given that there isn't any documentation about a function `spinOnce` in `rospy`. The [first answer on this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/110336/python-spin-once-equivalent/?answer=110701#post-id-110701) provides interesting links.

> But in fact callbacks do seem to be happening

- That's the normal behavior with `rospy`. `roscpp` and `rospy` *are not the same*. When it comes to callbacks, with  `roscpp` you need to use `spin()` or `spinOnce()` to process the events. With`rospy` you don't need it because when you create a subscriber it gets its own thread.

> In python when must spin() used ?

- If you want to keep your node alive until you request a shutdown or ros crashes. You can use it even if you don't have any subscriber.

> and when is spinOnce() used?

- Never, it doesn't exist.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2021-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3